SimpleJdbcCall does not see postgres functions named in uppercase
I have spring boot application where I need to call the postgres function by passing the schema and function name dynamically as a parameter. To do this, I use SimpleJdbcCall:
String result = new SimpleJdbcCall(datasource);
        .withSchemaName("TEST")
        .withFunctionName("get_data")
        .withReturnValue()
        .executeFunction(Integer.class);

When executing, I get the error "Unable to determine the correct call signature - no procedure/function/signature for 'get_data'.
Through experimentation, I found that the problem arises due to the fact that the name of the Postgres schema is indicated in uppercase. If you rename the scheme in lowercase, the code is executed without errors.
I found the reason for this problem in the code of PgDatabaseMetaData class, which comes with the library PostgreSql-42.2.1.jar:

It turns out that the driver only works with schemes with names in lowercase. Is there a way to change this behavior?
UPDATE:
As I discovered, due to the fact that calling "is StoresUpperCaseIdentifiers" always returns false, and calling "isStoresLowerCaseIdentifiers" always returns true for Postgres (screenshot above), the schema name is always converted to lowercase. I have given the code below:


You are ignoring the storesLowerCaseIdentifiers, storesUpperCaseIdentifiers and all the other combinations. The issue is that to maintain upper case the identifier needs to be properly double quoted per Identifiers. I don't use JDBC so all I can do is point you at JDBC quote identifiers.

Unfortunately, this does not work with SimpleJdbcCall, when specifying the name of objects through "withSchemaName" and "withFunctionName". In particular, the "schemaNameToUse" method of the "GenericCallMetadataProvider" class always returns the schema name in lowercase, regardless of whether it is enclosed in quotation marks or not (see my last update).

Then this is an issue you need to bring up with Spring Boot here Issues.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with "Spring Boot", most likely it's related to jdbc.
